# Logical and in verilog

Tags: verilog, logical-operators

I am trying to do data shifting and then doing it "logical and" with 255 i.e. 11111111. But I am getting 1 on the last bit. Other bits aren't changing. Data shifting is correct but I'm having problem in "and" operator.
Here is the code:

```
module Data_shiftin(
input reset_n, clk,
input [31:0]    data_in,
output [31:0] data_out
);
reg [31:0] data_R24;
reg [31:0] data_R16;
reg [31:0] data_R8;
reg [31:0] data_R;
reg [31:0] and_R16;
reg [31:0] and_R8;
reg [31:0] and_R;
integer a=255;

always @ (posedge clk)
  begin 
    data_R24[7:0]<=data_in[31:24];
  end

always @ (posedge clk)  
  begin
    data_R16[15:0]<=data_in[31:16];
     and_R16[15:0]<= a[7:0] && data_R16[15:0];
  end

always @ (posedge clk)  
  begin
    data_R8[23:0]<=data_in[31:8];
     and_R8[23:0]<= a[7:0] && data_R8[23:0];
  end  
always @ (posedge clk)  
  begin
    data_R[31:0]<=data_in[31:0];
     and_R[31:0]<= a[7:0] && data_R[31:0];
  end  
endmodule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&&` is logical AND. `&` is bitwise.

Are you sure you want a logical AND? Your storing the result in a 16, 24 and 32 bit register but logical and only ever has a 1 bit output. It is 1 bit as it is typically used in an if expression which has to be true or false, multi bit values would not mean anything.

Typical usage :

```
reg [1:0] a, b;
wire check;
check =  (a==2'b01) && (b==2'b10) ; //1 bit output
always @* begin
  if ( (a==2'b01) && (b==2'b10) ) begin
  //..

//Bitwise
wire [1:0] e;
e = a & b ; //=>2'b00
```

The result from `&&` is 1 bit, the result from the boolean expression is true or false.

`&` does not alter the width, it simply ands each bit in turn;

```
wire [1:0] e;
assign e = a & b ; //=>2'b00
```

Could also be done as:

```
e[0] = a[0] && b[0];
e[1] = a[1] && b[1];
```

Comment: It was printing mistake in book. Thanks! It was bitwise and :)

Comment: Glad to help @AwaisHussain, It would be good if you could submit the mistake to the book (publisher), and it should be included in the errata! Saying that they never publish the mistakes I point out to them.

Comment: I have mailed to publisher. I am hoping to get response soon.